# Android - Annotating Retrofit2 POST / PATCH Request Body with something similar to @SerializedName

Tags: java, post, request, gson, retrofit2

If the POST / PATCH body needs to look like this

```
{
    "class_name" : {
        "field_a" : "fjdksljf"
        "field_b" : "jfsljd"
        ...
        etc.
    }
}
```

and I have a POJO

```
public class ClassName () {

    @SerializedName("field_a")
    String fieldA;

    @SerializedName("field_b")
    String fieldB;

    ... etc.
}
```

and I want to pass it as

```
@PATCH("endpoint_url")
Call<ResponseBody> testFunction(@Body ClassName class)
```

How can I annotate the class itself with the `class_name` mapping needed for the JSON request **without** creating a RequestClass that wraps ClassName and annotates it with serialized name there?

(I tried annotating the class with `@SerializedName` but it gives me a "not applicable to type" warning.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a good solution for me. While it is possible to wrap it in another class, it doesn't really make sense in my use case since most of my POST bodies require a JSON key for the POJO I'm sending.

```
// to use the necessary @SerializedName annotations
String classNameJson = new Gson().toJson(className);    // {"field_a": "fjdksljf", "field_b" : "jfsljd", ... etc.}
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
     // must make this a new JSONObject or else it will handle classNameJson as a string and append unnecessary quotes
     json.put("class_name", new JSONObject(classNameJson));    
} catch (JSONException e) {
     // handle the error
}
String result = json.toString();
```

Result should print something like this `{"class_name":{"field_a": "fjdksljf", "field_b" : "jfsljd", ... etc.}}`

Got this idea from the following posts:

- [single key value to Json with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408579/single-key-value-to-json-with-gson)
- [JSONObject.toString: how NOT to escape slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563579/jsonobject-tostring-how-not-to-escape-slashes)
- [Java Append object to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724221/java-append-object-to-json)

Comment: Even so this code works properly using `POJO` structure is much better idea because maintenance is easier. After a while it will be hard to understand what this code does. See @Deadpool answer. It is much better in my opinion.